# For what values of $t$ is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

Given
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^t \sin \frac{1}{x^2} & \text{if } x\ne0 \\
0 &\text{if } x=0 \ 
\end{cases}.
$$
For what values of $t$ ($t$ is real) $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$?

I tried caclulate the right derivative at $x = 0$, and it's $0$, but I'm having troubles calculating the left derivative.

Help please?
Thanks

Comment: You should say _why_ you're having trouble calculating it. P.S. what is the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} h^{t-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{h^2}\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I wrote this but what do I do from here? I'm having troubles with the exponents...

Comment: @user3697301 When does this limit exist? That's all you need to find.

Comment: I know but I can't figure out how

Comment: Come on show some effort. Don't just keep saying things hoping I'll give you the full solution. @user3697301

Comment: I said it exists when the left limit and right limit are equal, and I know the right is 0 but I dont know how to calculate the left because the exponent of negative number

Comment: ...........................................?